# Validating a Form?

Tags: jquery, submit, validating

I'm trying to send an alert saying "Thanks for Registering" after someone fills out my form correctly, but even if there is a mistake in filling out the form, sometimes it still says "Thanks for Registering". I'm using jQuery.

Can someone tell me what they think?

http://codepen.io/dpcarlson/pen/nvwqk

HTML:

```
<h2>Form</h2>
  <h1>Validator</h1>
  <div>
      <p id="labelforusername">Your Name</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="username" >
  </div>
  <div>
      <p id="labelforpassword">Your Password</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="password" id="password" >
  </div>
  <div>
      <p id="labelforverify">Re-Enter Your Password</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="password" id="verify" >
  </div>
  <div>
      <p id="labelforemail">Your Email</p>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="email" >
  </div>
  <div id="submit">SUBMIT</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  //Validate Form **********************

  $('#submit').click(function() {

    if($('#username').val().length === 0) {
      alert("Please Enter Your Name"), $('#username').css('background','rgba(0,0,600,0.3)');
    } else {
      $('#username').css('background', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)' );
    };

    if($('#password').val().length === 0) {
      alert("Please Enter Your Password"), $('#password').css('background','rgba(0,0,600,0.3)'), $('#verify').css('background','rgba(0,0,600,0.3)');
    } else if ($('#password').val().length <= 4) {
      alert("Please Make Your Password At Least 5 Characters"), $('#password').css('background','rgba(0,0,600,0.3)'), $('#verify').css('background','rgba(0,0,600,0.3)');
    } else {
      $('#password').css('background', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)'),
      $('#verify').css('background', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)');
    };

    if($('#password').val() !== $('#verify').val()) {
      alert("Oops, Seems Like Your Passwords Don't Match!"), $('#password').css('background','rgba(0,0,600,0.3)'), $('#verify').css('background','rgba(0,0,600,0.3)');
    };

    if($('#email').val().length === 0) {
      alert("Please Enter Your Email"), $('#email').css('background','rgba(0,0,600,0.3)');
    } else {
      $('#email').css('background', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.3)');
    };

  if ($('#password').val().length > 4 && 
    $('#password').val().length !== 0 &&
    $('#verify').val().length > 4 &&
    $('#verify').val().length !== 0 &&
    $('#username').val().length > 0 &&
    $('#username').val().length !== 0 &&
    $('#email').val().length !== 0 &&
    $('#email').val().length > 0 &&
    $('#password').val() === $('#verify').val()){
       alert("Thanks For Registering!")
}
  });

  //End Validate Form **********************
```

Cheers.

Comment: I think your click function should take in eventObject e so you can call e.preventDefault(). You never cancelled the click event which will submit the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of the way your if statement is structured. In the current design, an expression is used with a list of expressions in order to determine a logical state. However, it doesn't build when a comma delineated list is used in an expression, it just evaluates one at a time.

As a result, the last value is the one which is compared with true in your if statement. That means something this alerts true

```
if((false,false,false,true)===true)alert("true");
```

So really in order to show the "Thanks for Registering" alert all that has to be true is

```
$('#password').val() === $('#verify').val()
```

when in reality you probably wanted this

```
if ($('#password').val().length > 4 && 
    $('#password').val().length !== 0 &&
    $('#verify').val().length > 4 &&
    $('#verify').val().length !== 0 &&
    $('#username').val().length > 0 &&
    $('#username').val().length !== 0 &&
    $('#email').val().length !== 0 &&
    $('#email').val().length > 0 &&
    $('#password').val() === $('#verify').val()){
       alert("Thanks For Registering!")
}
```